# What does "historically suspect" mean in 'Trump's allies dismiss the criticism as politically motivated and historically suspect.'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source:  http://www.adn.com/alaska-news/nation-world/2016/05/28/rise-of-trump-tracks-growing-debate-over-global-fascism/

Please tell me what is meant by historically suspect here

> Trump's allies dismiss the criticism as politically motivated and ***historically suspect.***

Comment: They think comparison of Trump and his supporters to the fascist movements of 1930s Europe is specious.

Answer (score 1):

"Suspect" is not a noun. The adjective [*suspect*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suspect) has the following meaning:

> regarded or deserving to be regarded with suspicion: **doubtful**, **questionable**.

You can rephrase the sentence to

> Trump's allies dismiss the criticism as politically motivated and
>   historically **questionable**.

It means their criticism is historically unfounded and baseless.

[Merriam-Webster]